# Can't boot my VirtualBox VDI -- messed up storage setting

Tags: boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vdi

I messed some storage setting up in the VirtualBox GUI, and now I can't boot my VDI. I tried just creating a new VM and using the existing drive. That didn't work either.

I get:

[image]

This is what my storage settings look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that I can think of:

1. Your inserted SATA controller (U2.vdi) is wrong and you need to insert the correct one.
2. Your IDE Controller is empty (which is less likely than the first solution).

EDIT:
To resolve the first issue you have to follow these steps:

- right click on the U2.vdi and remove it by `Remove Attachment`.
- click on the `Controller: SATA`.
- on the right hand side of the selection, click on the `Adds hard disk` icon.
- select the `Choose existing disk` option.
- navigate to the address of your .vdi files and choose the right one (U3.vdi maybe?!)
- click on `open`.

Now check to see if it boots up with current settings. If *yes*, enjoy! if *no* then follow these steps as well:

- right click on the `empty` IDE controller and remove it by `Remove Attachment`.
- click on the `Controller: IDE`.
- on the right hand side of the selection, click on the `Adds optical drive` icon.
- select the `Choose disk` option.
- select the correct disc and click on ok.

Comment: This is not an answer but a text version of the second screenshot. It clearly shows that the IDE controller is empty and inserted SATA U2.vdi is not working. What can be done to resolve this ?

Comment: You're right, here is a step by step tutorial